# Shell script not recognising declared variables

Tags: linux, django, shell, sh, openvpn

I got a shell script with 4 variables .So far so good:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo keygeneration $1 $2 >> /tmp/logfile
touch /home/ubuntu/newproject/static/$1

KEY_NAME=$1
KEY_CN=$1

sh pkitool
```

there is really nothing complicated about it... I got a Django app which tells the user to type in Username ($1) and Password ($2). when I use the pkitool and give the 2 variables KEY_NAME and KEY_CA a content, it works... when I type in the Username and Password on the website the script even saves the content of the variable and saves it in /static. I can even execute the script itself in my shell when I pass 2 variables.... It looks like this then:

```
sh keygen.sh FooUsername BarPassword
```

the only thing that does not work is, when I type in Username and Password in the app, it won't execute the pkitool correctly and the 2 variables KEY_NAME=$1 and KEY_CN=$1 aren't declared.. but that is totally weird because it does save the variable $1 though in static Oo can you guys tell me how this could come ?

Comment: Should it be `KEY_CN=$2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your variables to have them picked up by sub-processes:

```
export KEY_NAME=$1
export KEY_CN=$2
```

Comment: Soz, I'm a stupid doge ... ^^ of course your answer was correct.. :D the reason my program didn't work properly was another ... "screw you linux root" ! however thank you :)